# Convert date time to milliseconds in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have currentDate:

```
var clockFormat = 'dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss a';
var currentDate = dateFilter(new Date(), clockFormat);
```

Is it possible to convert currentDate to milliseconds in AngularJS?
Or, how to call javascript function getTime which returns milliseconds?

```
var currentDate = dateFilter(new Date(), clockFormat).getTime();
```

Return error!

Thanks in advance,
Srdjan

Comment: im assuming you didn't google anything? [`Date.getMilliseconds()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmilliseconds.asp)

Comment: I tried that. And get an error "getMilliseconds is not a function".

Comment: i promise it's a function and it's supported by pretty much every browser, here's a [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/6fjg6dx8/) are you trying to use getMilliseconds on the return value of `dateFilter`??

Comment: I would use Moment.js

Answer (score 2):

Srdjan, I answered this exact question a few minutes ago for a different user who deleted the question. The reason why:

```
var currentDate = dateFilter(new Date(), clockFormat).getTime;
```

Does not work is because you are using the .getTime() function which is native to Date types on the dateFilter instead of the new Date() like so:

```
var date = new Date();
var currentDate = dateFilter(date.getMilliseconds(), clockFormat);
```

or as you mentioned in comments you want to use .getTime():

```
var date = new Date();
var currentDate = dateFilter(date.getTime(), clockFormat);
```

Comment: I am trying to help - can you be more descriptive? You mentioned to the other person who said to use .getMilliseconds() that you got an error that said it is not a function - you are getting that because it is not a function of dateFilter. Have you tried running this code? If so why did it not work?

Comment: I added a second example in my answer to show you how you can use getTime instead. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: But I don't understand why AngularJS refuse it.

Comment: It refuses it because you are using the getTime() function on a filter function by chaining it at the end. You have to do it to the actual date which owns the getTime() function. When you try what I put it works doesn't it?